# I cannot get the category id

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the script

```
$category_id = $cat->ID; /* <-- can get the id */
$getsubs = "SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy 
WHERE taxonomy = 'wpsc_product_category' AND parent = '".$category_id."' 
ORDER BY term_id ASC";
$subcats = mysql_query($getsubs);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($subcats);
wpsc_start_category_query(array('parent_category_id'=>$category_id, 'show_thumbnails'=> 1)); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php wpsc_print_category_url();?>" title="<?php wpsc_print_category_name();?>">
<?php wpsc_print_category_image(); ?>
<?php //wpsc_print_category_name();?>
<?php //wpsc_print_category_name();?>
</a>
</li>
<?php wpsc_end_category_query(); ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Am I using this correctly `$cat->ID`. Please help.

Comment: if I put only the id it works

Comment: var_dump($cat); i think its term_id not ID
we use ID for posts and term_id for taxonomies

Comment: thanks for the help, but i have answered my own question

I just used wpsc_category_id(); instead of $cat->ID;

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
 parent = '{$category_id}' ORDER
```

also use of `mysql_*` is deprecated so use the `pdo` or `mysqli` instead. My personal suggestion is pdo [Here is the good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: is there a simple way of doing this?

I just wanted to display products sub-categories when its in parent category

im using wp e-commerce plugin for wordpress